# My [MenuItem()] is not being added to the menu

Tags: unity, editors, menu

In Unity 5, I created a `ScriptableObject` class which adds itself to the Main Menu:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "MyFancyAsset", menuName = "My Framework/Objects/My Fancy Object")]
public class MyFancySO : ScriptableObject
{
    // Public and [SerializeField] data comes here
}
```

This code works as expected. When the code is compiled, I can see the new menu being crated and working (a "My Framework" entry appears, and when choosing My Fancy Object), it is created appropriately).

What I am trying to do is to create a method with extended functionality o be added to the menu. So I tried like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "MyFancyAsset", menuName = "My Framework/Objects/My Fancy Object")]
public class MyFancySO : ScriptableObject
{
    // Public and [SerializeField] data comes here

    [MenuItem("Assets/Create/My Framework/Objects/My Fancy Object (with more stuff)", menuItem = "My Fancy Object (with more stuff)")]
    public static void CreateInstanceWithMoreStuff()
    {
        // Now I create something, with logic based on what
        //   I can read in several files in the unity2d-extras
        //   repository.
    }
}
```

And although this code compiles with no errors, I don't see the new menu being created (but just the original menu created by CreateAssetMenu).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, remove the code that sets the `menuItem` variable in the attribute:

```
[MenuItem("Assets/Create/My Framework/Objects/My Fancy Object (with more stuff)"]
public static void CreateInstanceWithMoreStuff()
{
    // Now I create something, with logic based on what
    //   I can read in several files in the unity2d-extras
    //   repository.
}
```

For more usage examples, see the [Unity (5.6) Documentation for `MenuItem`](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/MenuItem-ctor.html)

On later versions of Unity (e.g. on 2017.3), your code logs an error:

```
Ignoring menu item My Fancy Object (with more stuff) because it is in no submenu!
```

---

As a side note, I'm not sure why `menuItem` variable is exposed by Unity. The [Unity (5.6) documentation for MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/560/Documentation/ScriptReference/MenuItem-ctor.html) (or later versions) do not mention these variables.

See below for the `MenuItem.cs` file. You are expected to use the constructors, and not the exposed public variables `menuItem`, `validate`, or `priority`.

```
public sealed class MenuItem : Attribute
{
    public string menuItem;
    public bool validate;
    public int priority;

    public MenuItem(string itemName);
    public MenuItem(string itemName, bool isValidateFunction);
    public MenuItem(string itemName, bool isValidateFunction, int priority);
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I will check that once home. But sounds good so far.

Comment: @LuisMasuelli also, you have a typo in your code. "Asses" instead of "Assets"

Comment: Sorry. This code is illustrative and not the actual code. However, only data fields exist in my actual code, and the methods I declared in the menu are also empty (yet).

Comment: @LuisMasuelli please mark this answer as accepted if it was the solution

Comment: I fixed... my typo. When I go back to home I will test it.